# Pegar somente dado ultimo mês usando R

Tags: r, microsoft-excel

Preciso extrair os ultimos valores mensais da coluna 2 do dataframe `ntnb45`. Há alguma maneira direta para fazer isso no R?

```
library(GetTDData)
ntnb <- download.TD.data('NTN-B')
ntnb45 <- read.TD.files(dl.folder = 'TD Files',maturity = '150545')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma solução rápida e simples com o `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
ultimos <- ntnb45 %>% group_by(anomes = format(ref.date, "%Y%m")) %>% filter(ref.date == max(ref.date))
ultimos

Source: local data frame [151 x 6]
Groups: anomes [151]

     ref.date yield.bid price.bid   asset.code matur.date anomes
       <date>     <dbl>     <dbl>        <chr>     <date>  <chr>
1  2004-09-30    0.0906   1022.04 NTN-B 150545 2045-05-15 200409
2  2004-10-29    0.0905   1033.15 NTN-B 150545 2045-05-15 200410
3  2004-11-30    0.0905   1002.60 NTN-B 150545 2045-05-15 200411
4  2004-12-31    0.0905   1018.52 NTN-B 150545 2045-05-15 200412
5  2005-01-31    0.0903   1035.64 NTN-B 150545 2045-05-15 200501
6  2005-02-28    0.0905   1045.57 NTN-B 150545 2045-05-15 200502
7  2005-03-31    0.0905   1059.98 NTN-B 150545 2045-05-15 200503
8  2005-04-29    0.0904   1076.44 NTN-B 150545 2045-05-15 200504
9  2005-05-31    0.0910   1039.66 NTN-B 150545 2045-05-15 200505
10 2005-06-30    0.0910   1049.90 NTN-B 150545 2045-05-15 200506
# ... with 141 more rows
```

Answer (score 3):

Eu não sei se há uma função que faça isto diretamente, mas consegui construir um algoritmo que aparentemente resolveu o problema.

Em primeiro lugar, separei a coluna `ref.date`, que possui as datas em formato "yyyy-mm-dd", em outras três colunas. Uma coluna corresponde ao ano, uma coluna ao mês e outra ao dia. Chamei este resultado de `datas`:

```
datas <- strsplit(as.character(ntnb45$ref.date), split="-")
datas <- matrix(as.numeric(unlist(datas)), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
```

Estou exibindo o código em duas linhas para ser didático. É perfeitamente possível rodar este comando em uma linha apenas.

Com o data frame `datas` construído, basta que atentemos a um fato que ocorre quando o mês acaba. Sempre que o mês muda, o dia "zera". Ele não volta a zero literalmente, mas o valor do primeiro dia útil de um mês é um valor numérico menor do que o ultimo dia útil do mês anterior. Assim, basta encontrarmos os locais em que, na posição seguinte, os dias ficaram com valor numérico inferior ao da posição atual. Isto pode ser obtido através de uma primeira diferença:

```
index <- which(diff(datas[, 3]) < 0)
```

o que este comando faz é calcular as diferenças do tipo `x[n+1]-x[n]`. Se `n` for o valor numérico do dia do mês, este valor será sempre igual a 1, exceto quanto o mês muda. Ou seja, o vetor `index` possui todas as posições nas quais o mês atual mudou. Agora basta selecionar as minhas correspondentes no data frame original:

```
ntnb45.ultimo <- ntnb45[index, ]
head(ntnb45.ultimo)
  ref.date yield.bid price.bid   asset.code matur.date
190 2004-09-30    0.0906   1022.04 NTN-B 150545 2045-05-15
210 2004-10-29    0.0905   1033.15 NTN-B 150545 2045-05-15
230 2004-11-30    0.0905   1002.60 NTN-B 150545 2045-05-15
253 2004-12-31    0.0905   1018.52 NTN-B 150545 2045-05-15
22  2005-01-31    0.0903   1035.64 NTN-B 150545 2045-05-15
40  2005-02-28    0.0905   1045.57 NTN-B 150545 2045-05-15
```

Para obter os valores da coluna 2 apenas dos últimos dias do mês, basta rodar

```
ntnb45.ultimo[, 2]
```